# How to get the root path of a web project in SpringMVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'd like to create a temporary folder at the root path of my web project for uploading files. I've googled that using:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void torrent2magnet(HttpSession session) {
    String uploadBaseDir = session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+File.separator+"uploadFiles"+File.separator;
}
```

can get a relative path to the web project. **But** there are 2 obstacles as follows:

1: `session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")` can act differently when using different containers (like tomcat or weblogic). In the worst case, it may return `null`.

2: I intend to write a `@Service` class, in which a method will be provided to return the root path of current web project. how can I get a `ServletContext` instance in my `@Service` class?

Is there a more elegant way to resolve this two problems? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why don't you provide the absolute path to your web application root as a configurable parameter in a properties file, database field or environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Just Implement `ServletContextAware` interface to get the ServletContext injected automatically. Override the `setServletContext` method. Please follow the [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ServletContextAware.html)

One more advice is that please have your upload directory outside your application.that's always a good design

Comment: Thanks! You mean I just write the path to a somwhat `/home/myself/uplodFiles`? Does it allow to write to a path which is not a sub path of the root of web project?

Comment: Yes absolutely! when the number of upload files grow, it will help in future

Comment: follow this link http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/08/spring-mvc-file-upload-example.html, Checkout UploadController.java. you will understand :)